# Right click uninstall/context in apps menu

Tags: menu, apps

Everytime I want to uninstall, or go to the file location of an app from either the app menu or the dock [plank], I always instinctively just right click them, although obviously the only options are to keep in dock or add to dock.

Is there anyway to add a small context menu that includes an Uninstall app, and maybe a file location option? Similar to how you get on android.

Thanks